# Are there abbreviations for the names of the days of the week?

Tags: português-europeu, abreviações

My app has an issue where pt_PT abbreviated names for [days of the week] were the full name and not the customary first 3 letters.

So instead of "domingo", I expected to see "dom".

In reality it's "domingo".

Is it always the case in pt_PT? In all instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it always the case in pt_PT? In all instances?

No. As the question itself states "[your] app has an issue" and one can find similar bug reports, e.g., [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418061) and [here](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/ICU-13592), which also list the expected results:

> "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", Sáb", "Dom"

Lower case is [also an option](https://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/pt_PT/):

> dom  seg  ter  qua  qui  sex  sáb

And other possibilities [include](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/abreviaturas-dos-dias-da-semana/15697):

> a) Se, Te, Qa, Qi, Sx, Sa, Do.
> b) 2ª, 3ª, 4ª, 5ª, 6ª, Sa, Do.

Though I should add that, while (b) is quite common, I've never seen (a) in use and I suggest avoiding it.

Comment: It's great that you found the ICU/CLDR bug reports about this! I tried but couldn't reproduce it on MacOS or Linux, so I figured that the bug had to be coming from some other library than the normal one those systems use. (This question feels a little bit like it would go on [pt.so] instead.)

Comment: @tchrist Now that you say it, it feels kind of obvious: Yes, it's probably not really about the language - on the other hand, the question is written in English... I'll if the OP clarifies it.

Comment: I think the question fits our site, even if pt.SO would be a better fit. The question itself boils down to "are there abbreviations for the weekdays?", which fits just fine here. :)

Comment: Hi @stafusa. My question is more about the language since I am not a PT speaker. I actually opened my own issue in ICU and was rejected. Had to understand why, since it didn't seem logical that the top IT companies voted in favor of leaving the current status que. It means that only pt_PT locale will have cut text in our app, in contrast with pt_BR which looks abbreviated "correctly"

Comment: @o_w There is no difference between Iberian and Brazilian Portuguese here. Who is "our app"? Your company's app?

Comment: @Lambie Yes, my company's app. Apparently for Unicode there is a difference, and after my issue, there was a round of voting. My "proposal" of 3 letters abbreviations seems to not hold favor.

Comment: @o_w Yes, and that would be because Friday abbreviates to Sex. Companies are very wary and want to be PC.